# If I have 3 <tr> elements, how do I only allow one to be highlighted when clicked at any one time? - CSS, jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Might be a bit difficult to understand based on the description but the JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/n8a76/4/

Basically what I want it to do, when you click on any of the elements in the first 3 boxes, I only want one element to be highlighted at a time. If you click on two or three elements (names, projects, etc) right now, it highlights all two or three. It only unhighlights an element when you click it again.

So I would like to see, click element 1, element 1 is highlighted. Click element 2, element 1 (in the same box) is unhighlighted, and element 2 is highlighted.

So each box, from my code it is called a `dashed-panel`, should be independent of the other.

So in theory, `John Brown` and `Jack's App UI` could be highlighted at the same time.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just remove the class from th sibling `<tr>` elements in the same table, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clients table tr, #stages table tr, #projects table tr').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('dash-elem-selected').siblings().removeClass('dash-elem-selected');
  });    
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/n8a76/6/), this still allows toggling on/off as well.

Comment: +1 for keeping toggling. Also, @marcamillion, you may want to update your selector to use `#stages table tbody tr` (note the tbody), unless you like selecting the thead row in the #stages table. ;-)

Comment: @elusive You deleted yours? Bummer. This one is nice though, but if you left it I would have upvoted you for trying :)

Comment: @Brad Christie thanks for that tip. I saw that and was going to get around to fixing it. Just hadn't gotten there yet :)